# How do I specify that I ranked first in a university which has alot of affiliated colleges?

Tags: university

I ranked first in my university in my undergrads, which had many affiliated colleges. How can I specify that in an essay in a compelling yet precise manner?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _ranked first in University_?

Comment: @Susmitha Are you ranked first of the whole university(a university exam) or just the college of your affiliation?

Comment: @sathyam I ranked first in the whole university

Comment: @scaaahu I mean I secured the first rank among all the students who took the same course as I did, including all the colleges affiliated to the University.

Comment: @sushmitachaudhari Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Making a note of the number of affiliated colleges might be fine. But I will suggest including the total number of candidates (students) in your batch that includes all affiliated colleges (if available) within which you've established your rank.

Comment: Thanks. I was apprehensive to write something like: "I ranked first among 500 students from different affiliated colleges under my University." Could I make it more precise and compelling?

Comment: @sushmitachaudhari: You may replace "different" with the no. affiliated colleges. That might make a stronger point if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it is perfectly fine to state that you **ranked 1** in the *university.*
In my case I had been asked to provide the number of students. I had no difficulty since mine was a National institute which is a university by itself, all I had to do is to count the number of students in my class. But in your case you might have to give a brief explanation about the affiliation, possibly **an attestation from the University and college**.